# Python Flask - Gravatar Issue

Tags: python, flask, gravatar

Using Flask - I've got the coding to get the gravatar image URL and I've printed it in the console to see if it's working and it is. I've got the hashlib md5 bit being put into a variable called Avatar.

And in my html file I have this to display the avatar

```
<img src="{{ avatar }}">
```

But nothing is displayed.

When I use inspect element, all that is in that part is this

```
<img src="">
```

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to pass the variable to the template....`return render_template('template.html', avatar=avatar)`

Comment: That was it. Thanks. One of those, "it's so simple but I can't find what the problem is" moments

Answer (score 1):

Since every user in an application may need an avatar, it is ideal to update the User model with a gravatar image/identicon. You can do this in `models.py`, as follows:

```
from hashlib import md5

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index = True, unique = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index =  True, unique = True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    def gravatar(self, size):
        digest = md5(self.email.lower().encode('utf-8')).hextdigest()
        return 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{}?d=identicon&s={}'.format(digest, size)
```

In your `<>.html` file, you can add the dynamic component as follows:

`<img scr="{{ user.avatar(<choose a size>) }">`

This should display an identicon image on your HTML file without the need to define `avatar = avatar` when rendering the HTML template.